# Access Query default value if not Match

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join

How can I formulate a query in Microsoft Access to produce the result table below from these two source tables?

***Table 1***

```
Item Code
---------
Item 01
Item 02
Item 03
```

***Table 2***

```
Item Code | Quotation
----------+----------
Default   |      5000
Item 01   |      1000
Item 02   |      2000
```

I want result Table must be like that:

***Result Table***

```
Item Code | Quotation
----------+----------
Item 01   |      1000
Item 02   |      2000
Item 03   |      5000 <== note no matching item code in table 2
```

Comment: Adjusted wording and formatting. Removed MySQL tag and repaced with MS Access tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to store the default value in a dedicated table rather than having to 'project away' the other values:

```
SELECT t1.ItemCode, t2.Quotation
  FROM Table01 t1,  Table02 t2
  WHERE t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
UNION
SELECT t1.ItemCode, t2.Quotation
  FROM Table01 t1, Table02 t2
 WHERE t2.ItemCode = 'Default'
       AND t1.ItemCode NOT IN ( SELECT ItemCode FROM Table02 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.No, T1.ItemCode, T2.Quotation
FROM TABLE01 T1 
INNER JOIN TABLE02 T2 
        ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
        OR (T1.ItemCode <> T2.ItemCode AND T2.ItemCode = 'Default');
```

Comment: I tried, but this have some error at last row: "missing ( or [ ...." somethings like that.

Comment: I want to fill not match row as the Default value

Comment: @user7795335 Please share the exact error what you're getting and what you're trying

Comment: Hi. I know what is problem here. After ON you must have (), that why the window error appear.